# Sort row in excel by the lowest value (min value) + concatenate

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a data array with column and row headers, I want to sort the rows in the array starting from the lowest value by concatenating the value with the column header name (tag). e.g

[Array example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDSOR.png)

Comment: How does US go from Other being 4 in the source to Other being 2 in your result?

Comment: sorry just a typo, the number should be 4

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. 

What have you tried so far ? Please show some code.
Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [ask]. You might also want to learn about [example].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now noticed the sort requirement, so edited to this:

[image]

Which does what is expected almost as it has problems with duplicate values, but I don't think it will be the best solution if you have the amount of data you mention in your comment.

Came up with this, using index() and match(), look at the second version :

[image]

Comment: This seems to work but the issue is that I have a big data array with more than 30k different rows and 40 different column names which I want to concatenate with, changing column names seems not very efficient.

Comment: @Lediana see the edit with a version that sorts, note the row above that small() needs to pick up for the sort, but duplicates prove to be an issue. This is probably better using vba given the amount of data you mention.

Comment: your solution worked perfectly, thank you for your time, problem solved!

Comment: @Lediana if it works for you, then please accept the answer using the check mark on the top left. Please check as from what I see it does not work with duplicates, but if your real data does not have duplicates then it may well be fine for you.

Comment: Me data has duplicates unfortunately and yes it looks like it doesn't work with duplicates. Can this be solved through vba code?

Comment: @Lediana probably, but what about a secondary sort alphabetically? would that be an option?

Comment: I am not sure how alphabetical sort would help in this case, since in your solution C7 & D7 are both "Military", one should have been "Education" but is not coz of the duplicate value '3' in the third row.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it right, but what I need is the lowest value to come first, that's a must, alphabetical sort is not relevant in my case, but if it helps in for the solution I can have my data sorted alphabetically both by column names and rows prior to applying the last formula.

Comment: what if i have the data concatenated ahead like 'Education 2', 'Military 3', 'other 4' would I be able to sort them afterwards based on the lowest number first, and not have the problem where 'Military 27' would come before 'Military 3'?

Answer (score 0):

Double lookups (where you need to locate a value in orderm to find the position of a related lookup which returns the desired result) can be complicate to write but are not necessarily taxing on calculation cycles.
Per your sample image, put this in B7 then drag right and down.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$2, AGGREGATE(15, 7, COLUMN($A:$D)/(INDEX($B$3:$E$4,MATCH($A7,$A$3:$A$4,0), 0)=SMALL(INDEX($B$3:$E$4,MATCH($A7,$A$3:$A$4,0), 0),COLUMN(A:A))), COUNTIF($A7:A7, "* "&SMALL(INDEX($B$3:$E$4,MATCH($A7,$A$3:$A$4,0), 0),COLUMN(A:A)))+1))&" "&SMALL(INDEX($B$3:$E$4,MATCH($A7,$A$3:$A$4,0), 0),COLUMN(A:A))
```

Comment: How does it deal with duplicates? Trying it, it seems to give me the duplicates mine gives...